# Can't find any element on selenium on some wepage with python

Tags: python, selenium, element

trying to build some bot that scrape a webpage, and can't access to elements on this webpage with any method that i know.

what am i doing wrong?:)

tried get this element with all find_elemenet_by... and nothing.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'https://www.elal.com/he/Pages/Bid2Fly.aspx#bidflyer/auctions/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome
driver.get(url)
wait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.bid-button")))

print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("half").text)
```

trying to get the links as a start and then scrape for data.

Comment: what is it saying? what is the output/error?

Comment: it doen't find them. if it is "find by elements" - it returns me empty list. if it "by element" it returns me this error msg: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: For some insight on how to use Selenium, Please visit [this page](https://github.com/deshwalmahesh/hashtags_followers/blob/master/Find%20followers%20of%20a%20hashtag.py) . I have used every type of ```find_elements_by``` in this.

Answer (score 2):

1. All the content of the website, you're trying to automate is in [iframes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) so you will need to invoke [WebDriver.switch_to()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) function in order to change the context to the required iframe prior to attempting locating elements

   [image]

   ```
   driver.switch_to.frame("frame")
   ```
2. [WebDriver.find_elements_by_classname](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_elements_by_class_name) returns [List](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) of web elements, moreover the elements don't have text property so you should be:

   - [iterating the list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/)
   - using [innerText](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) property

   Example code (I changed your CSS locator to [XPath](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) for better readability and performance)

   ```
   url = 'https://www.elal.com/he/Pages/Bid2Fly.aspx#bidflyer/auctions/'
   driver.get(url)
   driver.switch_to.frame("frame")
   wait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.bid-button")))
   for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='half']"):
       print(element.get_attribute("innerText"))

   driver.quit()
   ```

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing the elements in a variable?

like- `var=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("div.half")`

I think it should do if the class name is as you have described it is and it is not compound.

Comment: thanks for your answer. unfortunately, its not the solution im searching for. i tried some ways to point on the element. it is just one of them. in this case it returns me an empty list. (i think that i havn't mistake with the "class name" ot "css selector" at this case and etc.)

Comment: use an autocomplete library. It'll help you with these errors . Like if the method you want to use with the object is applicable or not.

Comment: be careful while using ```find_element_by``` and ```find_elements_by```. One returns a firt element it can find while the other returns a list of all the elements.